# There is no ".text" member after I type "GUIText"

Tags: unity, c#, gui, monodevelop, code-hinting

I want to write a text in game scene... but when I type...

```
void Update() {
     GUIText.t|
```

Then the code completion hints do not offer to complete this "t..." to `GUIText.Text`.

Why is that? And how can I assign text to display in Unity 5.6.4 (64 bit)?

Comment: More importantly, have you typed what you intended to type, and then tried to run it? Sometimes MonoDevelop will not show certain things that are indeed there (I think this is an issue with the assembly).

Comment: yes i typed what i want and then tried to run but the error say : " An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.GUIText.text'  "

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to reference a static member that doesn't exist.

We do not access like this:

```
GUIText.text = "whatever"; //trying to reference a static member that doesn't exist
```

but rather like this:

```
    GUIText guiText = new GUIText(); //have now created an "object" A.K.A. "instance"
//...or otherwise you can drag an "object reference" in via Unity's inspector.
    guiText.text = "whatever"; //now have the "object reference" on which "text" exists
```

Also remember that programming languages are nearly always *case-sensitive*, so you must be careful for example to use `GUIText` and not `GUItext` or `GuiText`. The names must be precise.

Comment: //...or otherwise you can drag an "object reference" in via Unity's inspector.  yes, i'm doing this way but then when i want to write `GUIText.Text` (in Update() ), there is no "Text" after `GUIText.`  .

Comment: Note that most components in Unity prefer to be created on a GameObject using `AddComponent` - trying to create free-floating component instances with `new` can cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: from `game object` i'm clicking on `creat empty` then from that empty object in `hierarchy`i'm clicking on `add component` in `inspector` then add `GUIText`, after that i creat `c# script` and drag it to that empty object , in that `c# script` ( `in update()` ) i write `GUIText.` but after that there is no `Text` .

Comment: @yatayama it sounds like you're forgetting to either: 1) type the field you drag your GameObject into as `public GUIText myGuiText` or 2) Use `var myGuiText = myGuiTextObject.GetComponent<GUIText>()`. Either way, you can then write `myGuiText.text = ...` (note that your access here is via an *instance* of GUIText, not via the class itself as a static property)